# Differential approach to solve the 'ant on rubber rope' problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have been trying to solve the [Ant on Rubber Rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_on_a_rubber_rope) problem myself, but I hit some end. Maybe I made a mistake.

The 'Ant on a rubber rope' problem describes an infinite elastic rubber band, whose end (denoted by $y$) is moving from the origin with a velocity $u$. On the rubber band there is an ant (at position $x$) which crawls much slower towards the end of the rubber band, with a velocity $v$ ($u>v$).

I am concentrating on the relative position of the ant to the end of the rubber band

$$\epsilon = \frac{y}{x}$$

So at the beginning the ant is at position $x_0$ and the end of the rubber band is $y_0$:

$$\epsilon_0 = \frac{x_0}{y_0}$$

This value would not change if the ant were stationary and not moving, as the ant's position would stretch relative to the rubber band. But the ant is moving, so after some time $\Delta t$ the end of the rubber band is at

$$y_1 = y_0 + u \Delta t$$

and the ant's new position is

$$x_1 = x_0 + \epsilon_0\cdot u\cdot \Delta t + v\Delta t$$

The second term is because of the stretch of the rubber band, the third term is the motion of the ant itself.

Now I calculate the difference $\epsilon_1 - \epsilon_0$ which I find to be

$$\Delta \epsilon = \epsilon_1 - \epsilon_0 = \frac{v\Delta t}{y_0 + u\Delta t}$$

and it follows

$$d\epsilon = \frac{v\,dt}{y_0 + u\, dt}$$

when I have not made a mistake. But if this is right, you can transform this equation to

$$d\epsilon y_0 + u\,dt\,d\epsilon= v\,dt$$

where you can neglect the double differential term and you end up with

$$\epsilon = \frac{v\,t}{y_0}$$

which I believe is not a correct solution.

Where did I made the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is in your use of the indexes zero and one like $x_0$ and $x_1$.

You found out the relative speed of the ant **at the fixed time $t=0$**, but... this should not be applied to all the relative speed at other times.

We should instead generalize your equations:

$$ \begin{array}{}
\text{The relative position:}& \epsilon_t &=& \frac{x_t}{y_t}\\
\text{The end position:}& y_{t+\Delta t} &=& y_t  +\hphantom{\epsilon_t} u \Delta t\\
\text{The ant position:}& x_{t+\Delta t} &=& x_t +\epsilon_tu \Delta t +v\Delta t   
\end{array}$$

The relative position is than changing as:

$$\Delta \epsilon_t = \epsilon_{t+\Delta t} - \epsilon_{t} = \frac{x_t +\epsilon_tu \Delta t +v\Delta t }{y_t  + u \Delta t} - \frac{x_t}{y_t} = \frac{ v\Delta t }{y_t  + u \Delta t} \neq \frac{v\Delta t}{y_0 + u\Delta t}  $$

So you will get

$$ \frac{d \epsilon_t }{dt} =\lim_{\Delta t \to 0}  \frac{\Delta \epsilon_t}{ \Delta t} = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}  \frac{v}{y_t + u\Delta t} =\frac{v}{y_t} = \frac{v}{y_0+ut} $$

This means that the relative speed $\frac{d \epsilon_t }{dt}$ of the ant is not constant $\frac{v}{y_0}$, but instead decreasing in time $\frac{v}{y_t}$ as the rope length $y_t$ is increasing in time.

This will eventually lead to:

$$ \epsilon_t = \epsilon_0  + \frac{v}{u} \log \left(1 + \frac{ut}{y_0} \right)$$

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing $t$, $\Delta t$, and $dt$ a bit.

Let $t$ be the current time, so at time $t$ the length of the band is $y = y_0 + ut$.

At time $t$, the ant is at position $x=\epsilon y$ moving at speed $v$ relative to the band. The change in these values during a time period $dt$ would be $dx = \epsilon\,dy + y\,d\epsilon = (\epsilon u + v)\,dt$ as $dy = u\,dt$ due to the band expanding. This is what you have derived, but expressed with $\Delta t$ instead of $dt$.

The speed of the ant relative to the band is $y\,d\epsilon$ which should be equal to $v\,dt$. You can solve this in terms of $x$, but as you seem to have realised, it is easier to do it in terms of $\epsilon$.

Since $y\,d\epsilon=v\,dt$, we get $d\epsilon/dt = v/y = v/(y_0+ut)$. You almost get to this, but since you have been using $\Delta t$ as both time $t$ and change in time $dt$, you end with the expression $\delta\epsilon=v\,\Delta t/(y_0+u\,\Delta t)$ and replace $\Delta t$ with $dt$, although one represents $t$.

Integrate $d\epsilon/dt = v/(y_0+ut)$ and set $\epsilon=0$ at $t=0$, and you get
$$
\epsilon = \frac{v}{u}\cdot\ln\left(1+\frac{ut}{y_0}\right).
$$

Comment: But where exactly did I made a mistake?

Comment: @Alex: Upon rereading, it may be that I misinterpreted your approach. I thought $y_0$ should be the length at time $t=0$ since you referred to "the beginning". However, later you seem to use $\epsilon_0$, $\epsilon_1$, etc, to be values at times $t$, $t+\Delta t$? In any case, you seem to use $\Delta t$ as both $dt$ and $t$, and when you replace $y_0+u\,\Delta t$ with $y_0+u\,dt$ instead of $y_0+ut$ it is unclear if you think of $y_0$ as the length at the start ($t=0$) or at the current time $t$ (in which case $y_0$ shold be replaced with $y$).

Comment: Yes, $y_0$ is the length of the rubber band at the start (t=0) and all values with index $1$ are the valued at time $t=\Delta t$. The equation for $\Delta \epsilon$ seems to be correct. So where is the problem?

Comment: @Alex: If at time $t=0$ you have $x_0=0$, so $\epsilon_0=0$, it should be clear that the expression for $x_1$ cannot be correct if $\Delta t=t$. If instead $x_0$ and $x_1$ had been the positions at times $t_0=t$ and $t_1=t+dt$, it would have made sense, but then you would need $\Delta t=dt$. Maybe you should try to rewrite it all in terms of differential equations $x(t)$, $y(t)$, since I think the unclear use of $\Delta t$ is causing problems.

Comment: No. At $t=0$ there is $x=x_0$. It is not zero. And I am asking what are the changes positions of the ant and the end of the band at some time $\Delta t $ later. I have no idea what time did elapse from $x=0$ to $x=x_0$. I start looking at the problem when $x=x_0$ at some random unknown time. I just ask the question what is the situation some $\Delta t$ later

Comment: Either way, the expression for $x_1$ is wrong. Try rewriting your solution in terms of $x(t)$, $y(t)$ and be specific about the initial condition: eg $x(0)=x_0$, $y(0)=y_0$. I suggest setting $x(0)=0$ as in the [original problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_on_a_rubber_rope) since any other starting point just corresponds to a shift in time.

Comment: What is the error in the expression for $x_1$ exactly? I am looking at the position of the ant after some time $\Delta t$. There are two effects: (1) the band stretches, and the amount the band stretches in a time $\Delta t$ is $\epsilon u \Delta t$. (2) the ant moves on the band itself with velocity $v$ relative to the band, that makes $v \Delta t$. I want to know what I am doing wrong. I am not interested in a solution, I want to know where my error is...

Comment: You treat $\epsilon$ as if it is a constant, which is ok in the limit $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$, but in the expression for $x_1$ it is not constant for $\Delta t>0$.

Comment: Yes, I treat it in the limit $\Delta t -> 0$...

Comment: When the expression for $x_1$ is only valid in the limit $\Delta t\rightarrow 0$, you should make that clear. It also means the result only applies at $t=0$. Again, write it all out in terms of $x(t)$, $y(t)$ to make it more clear; and if you are going to use $\Delta t$, it should be clear which are equalities and which are limits.